# Telethon: how to get information about yourself correctly?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to write my own client for the Telegram messenger in Python. I use the [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) library. I took the code example from their main page:

```
 from telethon import TelegramClient

 api_id = my_id
 api_hash = 'my_hash'

 client = TelegramClient('Test2Session', api_id, api_hash)
 client.start()

 print(client.get_me().stringify())
```

This code should output information about me to the console. When I run this code I get the error:

```
 AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'stringify'
```

in line

```
 print(client.get_me().stringify())
```

How to fix this error? How to receive information about yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because `get_me()` is a coroutine in the Telethon library, and you need to await it to get the result. You can use the `await` keyword to asynchronously await the result.

Try this:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = my_id
api_hash = 'my_hash'

async def main():
    client = TelegramClient('Test2Session', api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()

    me = await client.get_me()
    print(me.stringify())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio
    asyncio.run(main())
```