# Telethon: login not saved

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to write my own client for the Telegram messenger in Python. For this I use the [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) library. I take the example code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77744149/telethon-how-to-get-information-about-yourself-correctly/77744168#77744168) (the example code from the Telethon main page crashes on startup):

```
 from telethon import TelegramClient
 import asyncio

 api_id = my_id
 api_hash = 'my_ha'


 async def main():
     client = TelegramClient('Test2Session', api_id, api_hash)
     await client.start()

     me = await client.get_me()
     print(me.stringify())


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     asyncio.run(main())
```

When I launch the app for the first time, Telethon asks me to enter a phone number. The code is then sent to the account associated with that phone number. The library asks to enter this code and I enter it. The app then prints out information about me.

After finishing the application I have the following problems:

1. Telegram logs out on all devices, all sessions (including official clients) and I need to log in again.
2. When I restart the application, it does not automatically log in and asks to re-enter my phone number and code. But the code is not received and the application remains stuck at the stage of entering the code. I have to interrupt it manually. Even though the Test2Session.session file is created upon first launch.
3. If I change the first argument in the TelegramClient function (session name), then the code arrives and the application logs in, but the problems from points 1 and 2 are repeated again.

Please tell me what I’m doing wrong and how to log in to Telegram using Telethon correctly?

Comment: For your first point, see https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/4051.

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to maintain Session you should consider

**creating unique Session Names**

each time you make changes to your code or application. Session files are tied to specific session names, so changing the session name will force you re-logging in, which is kinda expected behavior.

**avoiding the use of same Session Name**

To prevent getting logged out on all devices, stop from using the same session name for multiple instances of your Telethon client. Each client should have a unique session name to avoid conflicts.

and lastly it would be **ensuring the Session file handling**

If your app repeatedly requests your phone number and code on every run, it is possible that the session file is not being saved or loaded correctly or appropriately. for this, we have to ensure that the session file is managed properly by specifying a path for the session file explicitly in your code.

try this out:
for **asynchronous** manner we can try out this:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl import functions, types
import asyncio

api_id = 'your_api_id'
api_hash = 'your_api_hash'
phone_number = 'your_phone_number'

async def main():
    async with TelegramClient('your_session_name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        await client.start()

        if not await client.is_user_authorized():
            await client.send_code_request(phone_number)
            code = input('Enter the code you received: ') # you can manage this implicitly (this is just for ex.)
            await client.sign_in(phone_number, code)

        me = await client.get_me()
        print(me.stringify())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```